# Why isn't my loop writing into the txt file?

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to write my loop into a text file, but it keeps writing it into the console and leaving the txt file blank.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
void Crack(string password, vector<char> Chars)
{
    cout<<"PASSWORD TO CRACK: "<<password<<endl;
    int n = Chars.size();
    int i = 0;
    while(true)
        {
            i++;
            int N = 1;
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++)N*=n;
            for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
                {
                    int K = 1;
                    string crack = "";
                    for(int k=0;k<i;k++)
                        {
                            crack += Chars[j/K%n];
                            K *= n;
                        }
                    cout<< "Testing PASS: "<<crack<<" "<<"against "    <<password<<endl;
                    if(password.compare(crack) == 0){
                    cout<<"Cracked password: "<<crack<<endl;
                    return;
                    }
                }
        }
}
int main()
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("pass.txt");


    vector<char> Chars;
    for(char c = '0';c<='z';c++){
    if(islower(c) || isdigit(c))Chars.push_back(c);
    }
    Crack("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz", Chars);

myfile.close();
}
```

added the full code 
I want it to write each input into a new line on a text document, but wherever I try to add

```
  myfile << c;
```

it gives me weird outputs and does not write into the text file

Comment: `but it keeps writing it into the console` Are you sure about that?

Comment: That code doesn't write anywhere! Please post the full code, but as you don't pass `myfile` as a parameter to `Crack()`, there's no way anything could be written to your file.

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Seriously, it is easier just to initialize the vector to the characters you want instead of writing a loop.

Comment: You never did anything to the file in the code that you posted. How are we supposed to know what `Crack()` does? By the way, to write to a file, you need to do `myfile << something`, instead of writing `cout << something`.

Comment: so from my full code I need to replace any couts with myfile?

Comment: Yes. Just opening a file does not magically make `cout` link to the file instead of the console.

Comment: is there a way to avoid my text file from exceeding a certain size?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive take on the problem which might be simpler, which you can adapt. It's worth noting that no matter which method you choose this problem will require checking 26**18 different passwords, which will take a LONG time. Maybe try it on shorter passwords.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ofstream myfile("pass.txt");

void Crack(string password, string crack, string buffer)
{
    if (crack.size() == password.size()){
        myfile << "Testing PASS: " << crack << " " << "against " << password << endl;
        if (password.compare(crack) == 0){
            myfile << "Cracked password: " << crack << endl;
        }
    }
    else{
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++){
          Crack(password, crack+buffer[i], buffer);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string Chars = "";
    for(char c = '0';c<='z';c++){
        if(islower(c) || isdigit(c))
            Chars+=c;
    }
    Crack("zzzzz","", Chars);
}
```